# Retrieve runtime stdout and store in variable

Tags: bash, shell

Basically I want to do some error handing in my bash script (task.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
# step 1
# step 2
# step 3
# step n
if [ -f "/tmp/foo.bar" ]; then
  # full_shell_output=?
  # Send email to admin with all the stdout before this
fi
```

I tried to run bash `test.sh | tee -a /var/log/test.log`, however, it doesn't work since when the script is still running the "tee" won't even started to work, however, I do want to give admin the useful information, that is the **full stdout**, how to achieve this please?

Comment: What's the issue here exactly? That you don't see the output on the console immediately?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I'm assuming that the issue is that tee hasn't flushed everything to disk when the content on disk is being mailed... but, indeed, since the OP isn't describing the problem in detail, it comes down to guessing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing, @CharlesDuffy was correct, the issue for me is: when some error occurred, I want to dump all the stdout content into email sends to admins, however, at that point, the "tee" process is now yet started since the script is still running.

Comment: @WayneYe, that's actually not accurate -- `foo | tee` starts `foo` and `tee` at the same time (streaming output from `foo` into the input of `tee` as it's written). The problem you're seeing is more likely to be buffering; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are right, I am newbie:) I just verified! Now could you please help me to read actually content from $stdout, this should be really straight-forward, but forgive me, I couldn't make it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stdout_log=$(mktemp -t stdout.log.XXXXXX)
exec >"$stdout_log" # redirect all stdout to file

# ...do things that need to be logged here...

if need_to_mail_the_log; then
  exec >/dev/null # closes, and thus flushes, the original log
  mail admin <"$stdout_log"
fi
```

Now, if you want to have it tee'd to the console, that gets a slight bit trickier, since you need to wait for `tee` to exit:

```
stdout_log=$(mktemp -t stdout.log.XXXXXX)
exec 3>"$stdout_log"
exec > >(flock -x 3; tee "$stdout_log")) # send stdout to tee to the file

# ...do things that need to be logged here...

if need_to_mail_the_log; then
  exec >/dev/null # close the handle writing to tee
  flock -x 3      # grab a lock on the log; this will only succeed after tee exits
  mail admin <"$stdout_log"
fi
```

---

Since the question includes "and store in a variable" -- ignoring the mailing usage given in your example, that can be as simple as the following:

```
stdout=$(<"$stdout_log")
```

That said, if you wanted to send the log in an email, you don't necessarily need to load it into a variable at all, even if you wanted to add headers and footers; a heredoc can do that for you:

```
mailx admin@example.com -s "log from some process" <<EOF
Hey! I ran that thing you asked for, and got this message:

$(<"$stdout_log")

Please look into it; thanks!
EOF
```

Comment: BTW, I had a thinko in the original here (closing FD 3 before trying to use it to lock); that's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you Charles, there is one thing not clear for me: mail admin <"$stdout_log", can you update this line to a echo or cat, so that I can have clearer understanding; or can you embed the content in "stdout" into a string variable, since it eventually with be part of the email body, thanks a lot!

Comment: @WayneYe, `$stdout_log` expands to the name of a file which contains redirected content. Thus, reading from the file is essential. That said, that particular approach is what you'd use if the log is the *entire* email body. If you want other content besides the log, then yes, there'd be some changes... but can you confirm that that's what you're asking about? I'm not completely clear on what you mean by your comment.

Comment: The typical `mail` command to mail content from a file might look like `mailx  -s "subject line here" admin@email.address.here <file-with-content-here`

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I believe your answer should work, however I was having trouble in reading content from $stdout, I tried this but not work:

while read line; do
  echo "$line"
done <"$stdout_log"

Comment: Right, because we ran a `exec >/dev/null` before that point, so `echo "$line"` writes that line to `/dev/null`. Maybe you should `echo "$line" >&2` for your testing.

Comment: Super awesome, >&2 works! You made me a day, thank you very much @ CharlesDuffy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73805/discussion-between-wayne-ye-and-charles-duffy).